# Create a remote couchdb database within ionic apps

Tags: android, cordova, couchdb, ionic3, pouchdb

I'm building an ionic 3 app, and I'm using PouchDB and CouchDB for synchronization. 
To create the remote databases, I used the db.info() command as recommended in the [official documentation](https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html#remote-databases):

> note: The remote database will not be created until you do an API call, e.g.: db.info(). The reason behind that is that the PouchDB constructor is completely synchronous, for ease of error handling (i.e. no asynchronous errors).

Here is the code I used in my app:

```js
let remotex = new PouchDB('https://' + auth + '@' + 'xxx.xx:6984/' + xx + '_xx');
return remotex
  .info()
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error : ', err);
    return err;
  });
```

This is working fine; the remote databases are created and the sync is working great **only** when I build my app in the debugging mode:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --buildConfig
```

But, the the remote databases are not created when in the release version:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release --buildConfig
```

The .info() method is returning:

```
{"status":0, "name":"unknown"}
```

Does the command ".info()" work only in debug mode ? 
Is there any other method to create the remote databases and make the sync working ?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that this is a cordova issue and not a pouchdb problem, I have posted an issue [here](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7068), but it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was a problem related to the SSL certificate that I configured on the CouchDB server. The certificate was self-signed, so when the app is in the debug mode, the cordova build process make it ignoring errors generated by invalid certificates. But this is not the case for release mode.

So I modified the way the app is built in release mode to allow it making "insecure" requests. As I'm building the app for Android, I changed the file 
*SystemWebViewClient.java* located in *project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/* this way:

```
         if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
            // debug = true
            handler.proceed();
            return;
        } else {
            // debug = false => comment this 
            //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error); => comment this

            handler.proceed(); // added this
            return;
        }
```

This is just a work around and should not be used in production mode. 
I found this solution [here](http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/).